# How to intercept handshake request sent by SockJS

Tags: angular, spring, interceptor, stomp, sockjs

I am trying to create socket connection between angular client and spring boot server.

```
const ws = new SockJS(this.addressStorage.apiAddress + '/socket', null, {
  sessionId: function (): string {
    return that.authManager.playerId + ':' + lobbyName + ':' + uuid();
  }
});
```

Upon creating SockJS instance, client sends request to my server.
[image: screen of console, showing handshake request]

Since I have enabled WebSecurity on server, I need to authorize every request, including sockjs handshake. So on creating SockJS, this window pops up:

[image: screen showing google's chrome login prompt]

I don't want user to write his login and password again when client creates socket connection with server. Unfortunately it's impossible to add Authorization header using SockJS so I decided to use interceptor.

This interceptor doesn't catch SockJS handshake:

```
export class SocketInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authManager: AuthManagerService) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req);
    // req = req.clone({
    //   setHeaders: {
    //     Authorization: this.authManager.basicToken
    //   }
    // });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

So how can I intercept SockJS handshake in order to automatically authorize SockJS connection?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I'm experiencing a similar problem and would like to hear your solution, if you have one.

Comment: @ThilinaAshenGamage Unfortunately I haven't. I just disabled security for socket connection

Comment: Hi @hdw3, thanks for the clarification. According to my current observations, we cannot do this programmatically in the client side due to limitations in the protocol implementations.